# Symfony stops working after user login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am trying to write a simple loginpage using Symfony 3.3. Therefor I followed the guide which I found on [the symfony page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html). Every time I try to log in with my user I get a http 500 error. I am using the build-in php server. I created my user using a trial page which I wrote before. The server only stops working when trying to log-in, although the log says, that the login was successful. Without the login all pages are working as expected. Also when I am using plain HTTP-Authentication everything works fine. This occurs only to me when I am trying to use form authentication. Even when I enter wrong credentials the error is displayed. Is there anybody who could help me?

My security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12

    providers:
    mariadb_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User


    firewalls:
       dev:
           pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
           security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: dashboard


     access_control:
        - {path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - {path: ^/user, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] }
```

Login Controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
    {
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $username = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render(":abistuff:login.html.twig",     array("last_username" => $username, "error" => $error));
    }
}
```

dev.log

```
[2017-09-20 19:37:00] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\LoginController::loginAction","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"localhost:8000/app_dev.php/login","method":"GET"} []
[2017-09-20 19:37:00] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-09-20 19:37:00] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"6fb00a","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"localhost:8000/app_dev.php/_wdt/6fb00a","method":"GET"} []
[2017-09-20 19:37:05] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\LoginController::loginAction","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"localhost:8000/app_dev.php/login","method":"POST"} []
[2017-09-20 19:37:05] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT a0_.id AS id_0, a0_.username AS username_1, a0_.password AS password_2, a0_.displayname AS displayname_3, a0_.is_admin AS is_admin_4, a0_.is_active AS is_active_5 FROM abistuff_users a0_ WHERE a0_.username = ? ["admin"] []
[2017-09-20 19:37:05] security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":"admin"} []
[2017-09-20 19:37:05] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the 
session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2017-09-20 19:37:05] request.INFO: Matched route "dashboard". {"route":"dashboard","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\User\\DashboardController::showAction","_route":"dashboard"},"request_uri":"localhost:8000/app_dev.php/user/dashboard","method":"GET"} []
```

My login.html.twig

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Awesome Font-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("lib/styles/font-awesome.min.css") }} ">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("lib/styles/main.css") }}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default spacing-top">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Eingang zum Abistuff!</h3>
        </div>
        {% if error %}
            <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user standard-fa-width" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input autofocus="" class="form-control" id="UserName" name="_username" placeholder="max.mustermann" type="text" value="{{ last_username }}">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key standard-fa-width" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="Password" name="_password" placeholder="Passwort" type="password">
                </div>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the servers error log say?

Comment: I am using the php build-in server. The only logfile I could find was the one I posted. I also tried using the 'php bin/console server:run -vvv' command, which told me the same as the log I posted.

Comment: Have a look at this post for creating an error log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122267/php-built-in-server-error-log-location (last answer)

Comment: It looks like there is a memory error. I uploaded my log [here](https://pastebin.com/Mv7ehLqV). Aditionally I uploaded my [Entity](https://pastebin.com/G4gYhkVe) and my [EntityRepository](https://pastebin.com/5AVZ7bQ2). I also recognized, that, when I am calling my login page, the php process starts filling up my 16GB of RAM.

Comment: Can't spot any error in your files. There are some issues with the built in PHP Server and 32/64 bit machines. Maybe you can try installing something like xampp, depending on your system.

Comment: Sorry for not writing for a long time, I was busy doing other things :/ I'll try setting up a webserver for development purposes and see if it works then...

Comment: So I tried again with an Apache2 webserver and it still crashes, and still gives nothing else than the things I already posted. Nobody?

Comment: You can try to increase memory_limit in your php.ini. Set it for testing purposes to 1024M.

Comment: I did that and now it fills the limit I set. So increasing the limit does not change anything. What I did was to downgrade from 3.3.10 to 3.3.2 and now it works as expected. Probably a bug in the framework?

Comment: Good to hear, that you got it going. You could crate an Issue with potential bug label on symfonies github place. This is really strange and deserves more attraction.

Comment: @Chris I have opened a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/24647)